# Checking 5 ints in an array if 3 are the same

Tags: c

I have a int array that contains five random numbers. I am trying to check if three of the numbers match.

```
int die[5] = {2, 3, 5, 2, 1};
int kind = 0;
int score = 0;
int i = 0;
int x = 0;

    for (i; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (x; x <= 4; x++) {
            if (die[i] == die[x]) {
                kind++;
                score += die[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue I am running into is the very first case it will compare itself to itself. Which will always come back true. And if I add a +1 to the index, it will end up going out of bounds.

If I start at 1 instead of 0, then when it goes to the second digit, it will return the same once it checks itself against the 2nd number(itself).

Comment: have you ever initialised your `i` and `x` ?

Comment: `it will compare itself to itself` try starting `x`from 1 instead of 0;

Comment: It's not clear whether you want _exactly 3_ to match, or _at least 3_ to match.  There are some simplifications to this problem that do not involve nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if i equals j and just `continue;` your loop.

```
for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
    // you can set x=i+1 and skip some numbers
    for(x=0; x<=4; x++){ 
        if(i==x)
            continue;
        if (die[i] == die[x]) {
            kind++;
            score += die[i];
        }
     }
 }
```

EDIT:
There are simpler ways of doing this (checking if 3 numbers are equal), but if you just want to skip an iteration, use continue.

Comment: Since `x` starts from `i+1`, `if(i==x)` will never be true.

Comment: Also `i<=4` is meaningless (vs `i<4`) because `x=i+1` will be out-of-bounds if when `i` is 4.

Comment: Both of you are right. I did not give much thought to this, I just wanted to show him how he can use `continue` statement. I changed it to simply x=0

Answer (score 1):

```
int die[5] = {2, 3, 5, 2, 1};

int kind = 0;
int score = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {          // last check will be die[3] == die[4] to avoid 
                                   // die[4] == die[4]
    for (x = i + 1 ; x < 5; x++) { // it always checks with the next element
        if (die[i] == die[x]) {
            kind++;
            score += die[i];
        }
    }
}
```